# How I do Insert a new record/row into a Oracle Database from Tkinter/Python Script?

Tags: python, sql, oracle, tkinter

I am having issue inserting a new record into mY Oracle Database from Tkinter/Python Script.  I have tried many different variations, but the code snippets below are my baselines, that I am working from for variations.  Any and all help/suggestions greatly appreciated.

```
def add_record():
username = grp_entry.get()

oracledb.init_oracle_client(config_dir='/Desktop')

conn = oracledb.connect(
    user="<username>",
    password="<password>",
    dsn="dsn")        
c = conn.cursor()

add_record = "INSERT INTO ut_om_reports VALUES (username = '%s')" %(username)

c.execute(add_record)
 
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

The error for the above is below.

--oracledb.exceptions.DatabaseError: ORA-00917: missing comma

Additional baseline snippet below.

```
add_record = "INSERT INTO ut_om_reports VALUES username = '%s'" %(username)
```

Error code for above below.

--oracledb.exceptions.DatabaseError: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with tkinter, since you would get the same error if you hard-coded `username` to be a string.

Comment: In sql, the INSERT is written like this in your case INSERT INTO ut_om_reports (username) VALUES ('%s')

Comment: If I hard-code a value in, it will work.  I should have put that in, my apologies Bryan.  Included Tkinter just in case I was messing something there as I am new to that part of the equation.

Comment: username = '%s' looks somehow strange. Better try simply  VALUES ('%s'). Still, that is not the safe syntax for insert. It should be something like insert into x_table (col1,col2,...,coln) values (val1, val2, ..., val_n). Please do not write SQL insert statements without the list of columns to insert into, for by writing only the values you have the recipe for crash when a new column is added to the table you sre inserting into.

Comment: @gsalem That statement definitely works but it puts the literal in of '%s' unfortunately.

Comment: @BogdanDincescu How do I get this part "(val1, val2, ..., val_n)" to take a variable that I am entering on Tkinter side?

Comment: If you don't want to use literals in your SQL, then look up how to use bind variables in python and python-oracledb module

Comment: @marcspector1972 https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/bind.html

Comment: @gsalem and @ astentx Thank you all for getting me started down the correct path.  Post binding, everything worked perfectly!!